# Show last viewed product view when user interact with push notification (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, segue, uistoryboardsegue

i'm storing last viewed product in my database, and i'm sending this product id,

Inside of the `didRecieveRemoteNotification` i can get the appropriate id from my aps dictionary with `objectForKey:@"product_id"` but I don't know what I should to from here.

I can successfully, push my view to static view controller using the storyboard identifier - I don't know whether it's the best practice or not - but I can't make it happen with dynamic products.

In web, i would be able to use it like post  show/:id but I don't know how to do this in iOS.

I'm sending push notifications from my backend, so I can manipulate however I want.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply send the product (or product ID and then look it up) to the destination view controller via a property:

```
MyViewController* vc = (MyViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"MyStoryboard" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyViewControllerIdentifier"]; //have to set the identifier in the storyboard
vc.product = product;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated: YES];
```

Inside `MyViewController.h`: (class names etc are for demonstration purposes)

```
@class Product;  // assuming you have a Product.h / m file defining a product object, inside the .m file at the top: #import "Product.h"

@interface MyViewController: UIViewController
@property (strong) Product* product; //or NSDictionary or however you are modeling your products
@end
```

Where you get the product object/details depends on where you're storing your data (e.g. Core Data, plist, etc)

Then inside `MyViewController.m` in the `viewDidLoad` method set up your view according to the product property.

(Note: Your question is a bit vague, so if this doesn't help, just edit your question / comment on my answer and I will update my response accordingly.)

Comment: is there any way to do it without doing any additional work on the viewDidLoad ? And thanks for the answer

Comment: Additional work? I don't know how you've implemented your view controller so I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: i mean without creating a corresponding data structure on the viewDidLoad of the destinationViewController

Comment: I suppose you could set all the properties of your product directly onto your view controller (e.g. name, price whatever) but that isn't very clean. Using a model class to represent view data is pretty simple and it's also pretty standard for web, which you say you have experience with.

Comment: I already have a Product.h :) that wasnt what i meant to ask, but before that i m having errors from your given code 

   for the first line : 
    //Incompatible pointer types initializing VC with an expression of type UIStoryboard
   for the second line: //property navigationController not found on object of type AppDelegate

Comment: oops, forgot the instantiateViewController part. Fixed.

Comment: i knew that you put myViewController as a reference, and i already declared appropriate viewController but still the warning for the first line and still error for the third line

Comment: OK... so instantiate a navigation controller and push onto that... It was just an example. However you navigate through your app is a separate issue from the question at hand. Based on your question it seems you've already figured out how to push the view controller using the storyboard identifier.

Comment: shim, one last question, how can i show the view like it was a part of the navigation stack calls?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Pass product id to the destination view controller:

StaticViewController* vc = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"MyStoryboard" bundle: nil];
vc.productID = productID;
[appdelegate.RootViewController presentModelViewController: vc animated: YES];

Inside the StaticViewcontroller, get the product detail based on the product id so it will work dynamically too.

Comment: You misspelled "modal" and presentModalViewController: animated is deprecated anyway.